# Sort -u (or sort | uniq) on a couple of columns but retain the info in a third column, and append it to the retained row?

Tags: sort, uniq

I'm trying to take a table like this:

```
a     b     hello
a     b     goodbye
g     g     test
a     c     I say
```

to collapse the table down to one row per unique entry on column 1 and 2, but without losing any of the info in column 3.  The values in column 3 could get appended as a comma-delimited list.  The result would look this:

```
a     b     hello, goodbye
a     c     I say
g     g     test
```

I'm out of my element figuring out where to begin.  Using `sort -k1,1 -k2,2 -u`, I get the following result:

```
a     b     hello
a     c     I say
g     g     test
```

I've lost the entry for "goodbye", but I'd like to keep it.  Does anyone know how to avoid throwing away the data in column 3, as in the above example?

Comment: How exactly are the columns of the table delimited?

Comment: The original table is tab-delimited, cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know a way to do it using `sort` alone, but you could "collapse" the values using awk for example and then sort:

```
$ awk -F'\t' '
    BEGIN{OFS=FS} 
    {k = $1 FS $2} 
    {a[k] = a[k] == "" ? $3 : a[k] "," $3} 
    END{for (k in a) print k,a[k]}
 ' file | sort
a       b       hello,goodbye
a       c       I say
g       g       test
```

With a recent version of GNU awk, you can avoid the external sort by setting the array traversal order via `PROCINFO`:

```
awk -F'\t' '
  BEGIN{OFS=FS} 
  {k = $1 FS $2} 
  {a[k] = a[k] == "" ? $3 : a[k] "," $3} 
  END{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"; for (k in a) print k,a[k]}
' file
```

Alternatively, with GNU datamash

```
datamash groupby 1,2 collapse 3 <file
```

or more verbosely (but more flexibly) with Miller

```
mlr --nidx --fs tab nest --implode --values --across-records --nested-fs , -f 3  file
```

Answer (score 0):

A two-stage solution in bash that employs temporary files:

```
$ cat table.csv
a       b       hello
a       b       goodbye
g       g       test
a       c       I say

$ WD=$(mktemp -d) ; while read K1 K2 V ; do echo -n ",$V" >>$WD/$K1:$K2 ; done <table.csv

$ sort -k1,1 -k2,2 -u table.csv | while read K1 K2 V ; do echo $K1 $K2 $(sed 's/^.//' <$WD/$K1:$K2) ; done
a b hello,goodbye
a c I say
g g test
```

The gist of this solution is using shell append redirection (`>>`) for gathering values for keys that are equal before sorting.

Answer (score 0):

It can also be done with `sed` function (sorry, it's not really human-readable) :

```
echo "a      b       hello
a       c       goodbye
g       g       foo
a       c       bar
a       b       test
a       c       I say" | sort -k1,1 -k2,2 | sed ":a N; s/\([^\t]*\)\t\([^\t]*\)\t\([^\t]*\)\n\1\t\2\t\([^\t]*\)/\1\t\2\t\3,\4/; ta; P; D; ba;"
```

And the output is, as expected:

```
a       b       hello,test
a       c       bar,goodbye,I say
g       g       foo
```

- first sort, then use `sed` instead of `uniq`.
- `N;` will ask `sed` to work on 2 lines (or "one more line") instead of 1.
- `s/.../.../` will merge the two lines.

  - `\([^\t]*\)` will take a column (as many chars as possible, with not `\t`).
  - `\t` is a tab (separator).
  - `\n\t\1\t\2\t` checks if we have a second line with 2 similar first columns.
  - `/\1\t\2\t\3,\4/` transforms the 2 lines into one, with the same first and second column, and the third column is merged.
- `:a ... ta;` is like a `while` loop (do it again while `s` substitution worked).
- `P; D;` if we are here, the `s` failed, so we have two "different" (on first or second column) lines in pattern space. `P` prints the first line (with probably merged lines), and `D` deletes the line we printed.
- `ba;` loops while it can read lines (with currently 1 line in pattern space).